# Python (Requests) getting KeyError 'historical'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-requests

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def stockpriceanalysis(stock):
    stockprices = requests.get(f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/historical-price-full/{stock}?serietype=line")
    stockprices = stockprices.json()

    #Parse the API response and select only last 1200 days of prices
    stockprices = stockprices['historical'][-1200:]

    #Convert from dict to pandas datafram

    stockprices = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(stockprices)
    stockprices = stockprices.set_index('date')
    #20 days to represent the 22 trading days in a month
    stockprices['20d'] = stockprices['close'].rolling(20).mean()
    stockprices['250d'] = stockprices['close'].rolling(250).mean()

    stockprices[['close','20d','250d']].plot(figsize=(10,4))
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.title(stock + ' Moving Averages')
    plt.axis('tight')
    plt.ylabel('Price')
```

While trying to execute this code from my Raspberry Pi 3 with venv, I get the "KeyError 'historical'"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have forgot to provide the **api key**. I have run this code and it is asking me for an api key.

```
{'Error Message': 'Invalid API KEY. Please retry or visit our documentation to create one FREE https://financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs'}
```

Check the [official docs](https://financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs).

Comment: The user should **not** provide an API key. They likely have one, but won't post it for security reasons.

Comment: Yep, I fixed the apikey and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. @programmerwannabe